# How i can set background picture for table view and UIView from other class

Tags: iphone, ios, observer-pattern

I've got some url with picture when my player go play. And I want set a background picture to all my views. How I can do this? I need example code.

Comment: How are your views controllers taht suppose to have same background?Do they they their own view controllers

Comment: Yes, and background must change dynamic

Answer (score 1):

2 approaches

1) Write a cateogory on ViewController and change the background image in the category.

2) you can set the background image of your main window and set background image of all your views to clear colour.

I would go for the first approach its more elegant

Comment: >Write a cateogory on ViewController and change the background image >in the category.
can u write example?